# TSQL Query - Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the follwoing.

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

CREATE TABLE #Table (id int, row# int, Info varchar(10),
                        clm11 varchar(10), 
                        clm21 varchar(10), 
                        clm31 varchar(10),
                        clm41 varchar(10), 
                        clm51 varchar(10), 
                            clm12 varchar(10), 
                            clm22 varchar(10), 
                            clm32 varchar(10),
                            clm42 varchar(10), 
                            clm52 varchar(10), 
                                clm13 varchar(10), 
                                clm23 varchar(10), 
                                clm33 varchar(10),
                                clm43 varchar(10), 
                                clm53 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT 1, 100, 'Text', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5','Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14', 'Col15','Col21', 'Col22', 'Col23', 'Col24', 'Col25'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 100, 'Text', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,'Col21', 'Col22', 'Col23', 'Col24', 'Col25'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 100, 'Text',  'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5','Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14', 'Col15', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 100, 'Text',  'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 100, 'Text',  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14', 'Col15', 'Col21', 'Col22', 'Col23', 'Col24', 'Col25'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 100, 'Text',  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14', 'Col15', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 100, 'Text',  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Col21', 'Col22', 'Col23', 'Col24', 'Col25'

SELECT * FROM #Table


/* Desired output

ID  Clm1    Clm2    Clm3    Clm4    Clm5
1   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
1   Col11   Col12   Col12   Col14   Col15
1   Col21   Col22   Col23   Col24   Col25
2   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
2   Col21   Col22   Col23   Col24   Col25
3   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
3   Col11   Col12   Col13   Col14   Col15
4   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
5   Col11   Col12   Col13   Col14   Col15
5   Col21   Col22   Col23   Col24   Col25
6   Col11   Col12   Col13   Col14   Col15
7   Col21   Col22   Col23   Col24   Col25

*/


--- My Try
SELECT Id, FieldCode, FieldValue 

FROM ( SELECT id, clm11, clm21, clm31, clm41, clm51, clm12, clm22, clm32, clm42, clm52, clm13, clm23, clm33, clm43, clm53 FROM #Table ) MyTable

UNPIVOT
(FieldCode FOR FieldCodes IN ( clm11, clm21, clm31, clm41, clm12, clm22, clm32, clm42, clm13, clm23, clm33, clm43))AS CODE

UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldValues IN (clm51, clm52, clm53))AS FieldValues
WHERE RIGHT(FieldCodes,1) = RIGHT(FieldValues,1)


DROP TABLE #Table
```

I am trying to take ID and Clm11 to Clm53 (set of 5 columns) and if a set (5 Col's) have values(NON-NULL set), put them in a separate record along with ID as shown in "Desired Output" section. I have just shown 15 columns (Clm11-Clm51, Clm12-Clm52, and Clm13-Clm53) but there can be more set.

Please help.

TEMP Update:

```
select *
from (select id,
             (case when n = 1 then clm11
                   when n = 2 then clm21
                   when n = 3 then clm31
                   when n = 4 then clm41
                   when n = 5 then clm51
              end) as col1,
              (case when n = 1 then clm12
                   when n = 2 then clm22
                   when n = 3 then clm32
                   when n = 4 then clm42
                   when n = 5 then clm52
              end) as col2,
              (case when n = 1 then clm13
                   when n = 2 then clm23
                   when n = 3 then clm33
                   when n = 4 then clm43
                   when n = 5 then clm53
              end) as col3
      from #table t cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5) n
     ) t
where coalesce(col1, col2, col3) is not null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this with just a series of `union all`:

```
select id, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col15
from #table
where col11 is not null or col12 is not null or col13 is not null or
      col14 is not null or col15 is not null
union all
select id, Col21, Col22, Col23, Col24, Col25
from #table
where col21 is not null or col22 is not null or col23 is not null or
      col24 is not null or col25 is not null
union all
select id, Col31, Col32, Col33, Col34, Col35
from #table
where col31 is not null or col32 is not null or col33 is not null or
      col34 is not null or col35 is not null;
```

EDIT:

Yes, there is a way to handle this with a single table scan.  The idea is to use a separate counter table and lots of case statements.  Here is the code structure:

```
select *
from (select id,
             (case when n = 1 then col11
                   when n = 2 then col21
                   when n = 3 then col31
              end) as col1,
             . . .
      from #table t cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
     ) t
where coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) is not null;
```

This uses a subquery to define the columns, so the `where` clause does not have to repeat the ugly `case` logic.

EDIT 2:

The full query looks like *5* case statement with three clauses each, rather than three case statements:

```
select *
from (select id,
             (case when n = 1 then clm11
                   when n = 2 then clm12
                   when n = 3 then clm13
              end) as col1,
              (case when n = 1 then clm21
                   when n = 2 then clm23
                   when n = 3 then clm23
              end) as col2,
              (case when n = 1 then clm31
                   when n = 2 then clm32
                   when n = 3 then clm33
              end) as col3,
              (case when n = 1 then clm41
                   when n = 2 then clm42
                   when n = 3 then clm43
              end) as col4,
              (case when n = 1 then clm51
                   when n = 2 then clm52
                   when n = 3 then clm53
              end) as col5
      from t cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5) n
     ) t
where coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) is not null;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4843c/3).

Comment: This works as required. However, I believe that this "scans" the table at least 3 times (because right now we have 3 sets of 5 columns). If I have like 25 sets (125 columns), it will "scan" the table 25 times? Although this sln is simply beautiful and beautifully simple, is there any way to use (un)pivot or something where the query is a bit smaller?

Comment: I am confused after reviewing your latest method. Please review the TEMP Update section of the op to see what I am trying...don't think I'm following you.

Comment: @user1569220 . . . That query is what I'm thinking of to avoid multiple table scans.

Comment: Gordon, I am not sure if I wrote the query as you intended as I am not getting the same/similar result/# columns etc as your first approach. Did I write the query properly? Thx for your feedback. How are you querying col4/col5?

Comment: Works great (BIG THANKS!). I am trying to understand the CASE and CROSS JOIN logic. Would you mind explaining this in a bit detail (why this works and etc)...don't want to ctrl + c & ctrl + v. In meanwhile, I will try to figure it out.